# How inspect RScript requests at dashDB?

Tags: ibm-cloud, rscript, dashdb

I try to make a POST for RScript in dashDB. Normally my code return 200 for the request, but my code doesn't run.

I would like to inspect a log in dashDB, but I don't find in the documentation, how I can make that?

Thanks!

Comment: What service are you using? All of the dashDB services have been renamed recently. The new names are Db2 Hosted (was IBM DB2 on Cloud), Db2 on Cloud (was IBM dashDB for Transactions), and Db2 Warehouse on Cloud (was IBM dashDB for Analytics).

Comment: I'm using Db2 Warehouse on Cloud

Comment: Thank you Ricardo. That information will help me get the attention of the right team.